# How to run a react-native repo off of GitHub

Tags: react-native, github, npm

I am on a Mac and I am trying to download a project my team is working on from GitHub and work on it. I cloned the repo and when I tried to use

```
react-native run-ios
```

I get the error message: 
**Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.**
I have tried to use

```
npm install
```

on the folder but it will still not run. Any help?

Comment: you are missing the cli(`npm install -g react-native-cli`)

Comment: Hmm I just tried this, still didn't work, great idea tho

Comment: is it a expo project?